# How to make an elegant design in this situation?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a method like this:

```
   public void foo(String str){

    do.something();
    do.anotherthing();
    do.somethingelse();

    if(str.compareTo("choiceA")==0){
    do.somethingforA();
    }
    else if(str.compareTo("choiceB")==0){
    doanother.somethingforB();
    doelse();
    }
    else if(str.compareTo("choiceC")==0){
    dosomeother.somethingforC();
    doblahblah();
    writeblabla();
    }

}
```

i want to design the code as defining different classes or methods for A, B and C.

but there is many lines (first three lines of method) that A, B and C sharing.

if i generate different method for A, B and C, i will have to change every method when i have to maintain in the future, thus i wont be able to get the help of designing code with a design pattern approach.

what do you advise?

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you looking for is `polymorphism`.

There are two **"proper" object-oriented** ways to do what you want. My personal preference goes to the second one, I'll tell you why.

- **Inheritance**: Have a superclass (maybe abstract) in which your method does all the common stuff (`do.something();`, `do.anotherthing();` and `do.somethingelse();`. Then this method should call another `abstract` method. You then define three subclasses of that class, each for one of the different choices ("choice A", "choice B" and "choice C"). Each of your subclass implement the method in a different way, and does what you need to do.
- **Composition**: Instead of having subclasses, have an interface injected into the object that contains method `foo`. This interfaces then has three different implementations, one for "choice A", one for "choice B" and one for "choice C".

Personally I prefer **composition over inheritance**, because it usually produces a code that is more readable, less complicated, less buggy and *a lot* more testable (if you use an interface as suggested, then you can mock it in your unit-tests of the main class). It also ensures separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

If you're copy pasting code, you're doing it wrong ;)

How about creating a base abstract class that has the method foo, and an abstract method doTheSomething. You then extend it with A,B and C, and implement only the abstract method doSomething.

Your code then just needs to figure out the string based switch (would be a real simple switch in Java7, btw), get the right class, and run foo, which would in turn run the overloaded abstract method doSomething.

Sorry that this is such a general idea, but you don't give many details on whether your actions for A B and C are similar, or belonging to the same object, etc... So take it as a possibility and check if it remotely fits your case! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i want to ask if i generate an abstract method i have to copy and paste first three lines in every implementation, and when maintain i have to change all implementations . this is the problem, sharing first three lines.

Comment: Right, I need better syntax to explain this then, I'm editing the answer with an example